# operator != "seems" not working with char

Tags: c++

I have a problem, this is the code:

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main(){

    struct signUP{
        /........./
        char userGENDER;
    }signUP1;

    cout << "Gender [m]= MALE / [f]= FEMALE: ";
    while (signUP1.userGENDER != 'm' || signUP1.userGENDER != 'f'){
        cin >> signUP1.userGENDER;
        if (signUP1.userGENDER != 'm'){
            cout << "ERROR: Failed requirements.\nTry again.\n";
        } else if (signUP1.userGENDER != 'f'){
            cout << "ERROR: Failed requirements.\nTry again.\n";
        }
    }
}
```

An user have to compile a signup form, he must specify which gender he is by pressing "m" for MALE, "f" for female.
If he press something different from "m" or "f" an errors pops up and he can retry.

Build > Compile all fine, it starts with **"Gender [m]=MALE / .....: "**.
I can press everything, he doesn't find out if i press **"f"** or **"m"**, it's like there is an error in **"while"**, **probably the operator !=**.
I tried with ==, or != && !=, or == && ==, or == || ==.

EDIT1: Also i tried to move **"cin << signUP.userGENDER;"** out of while, or put it in differents places.

I'm pretty inexperienced with c++ that's why i need your help.

Comment: Your code has undefined behaviour because it attempts to read an uninitialized variable.

Comment: It is also wrong if it were C. See the answer by Andrew. And use a do..while loop or such..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char userGENDER = 'x'; //some initial value, would work without initialization

cout << "Gender [m]= MALE / [f]= FEMALE: ";
cin >> userGENDER;
while (userGENDER != 'm' && userGENDER != 'f') {
    cout << "ERROR: Failed requirements.\nTry again.\n";
    cin >> userGENDER;
}
```

Your code was unnecessarily complex and you seem to have problems understanding how boolean evaluations are done.

We can go through the cases of your code, that is "gender != m || gender != f".
Suppose gender = m then "gender != m || gender != f" becomes "m != m || m != f" which is "false or true" which is true. So, despite the input being correct, the case for it not being correct is started. Another possibility to avoid this is a more controlled negation:

```
while (not (userGENDER == 'm' || userGENDER == 'f')) {
```

this reads more like one thinks: while the gender is not either male or female, iterate.

Or, if you really need it:

```
bool valid_gender(const char inp){
    return inp == 'm' or inp == 'f';
}

while (not valid_gender(userGENDER)) {
```

btw, userGENDER is an unusual naming. Usually, one goes with underscores or camelcase, like user_gender or userGender.

Comment: Np. Another thing, there are other platforms for getting your code reviewed - as a beginner, that is something you want to do. Getting opinions on your style etc. Not on this somewhat small code, but when you do larger programs. Another thing I'd change in your code would be to get rid of using namespace std;, std is quite big and this can lead to name collisions. Better use something like using std::cout; using std::endl;. This applies mostly to big libraries, not to small ones, but I tend to do it even then, to make it clear which function comes from where.

Comment: I am thinking about your use of `not`. It does seem to read nicer. And it's correct code...But I'm so used to reading `!` in C and C++ code....

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius I guess that especially C programmers prefer the ! because it is shorter to write and has this formula-touch. I try to use "not" preferably for it's readability, but in the end, this is personal style. I guess some people would frown upon my use of the word "or" instead of ||, which would shave off some nano-seconds, but in such a case, I place readability over micro optimization.

Answer (score 2):

You want to error message and loop while there is invalid input, otherwise you want to break:

```
while (true)
{
    cin >> signUP1.userGENDER;
    if (signUP1.userGENDER == 'm' || signUP1.userGENDER == 'f')
        break;
    else
        cout << "ERROR: Failed requirements.\nTry again.\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic is wrong in the `while` statement:

```
while (signUP1.userGENDER != 'm' || signUP1.userGENDER != 'f') ...
```

If `signUP1.userGENDER` is `'m'`, it can't be equal to `'f'`, so the second part is true.  If `signUP1.userGENDER` is `'f'`, it's not equal to `'m'`, so the first part is true.

The `while()` clause is therefore always true.  It's hard to tell from your code fragment, but you probably want `&&` instead of `||` in the `while` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems in your while condition one of conditions will allways be true cause a char cannot be m and f at the same time
Same at if condition

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    struct signUP{ 
        char userGENDER;
    }signUP1;
    cout << "Gender [m]= MALE / [f]= FEMALE: ";
    while ((signUP1.userGENDER != 'm') && (signUP1.userGENDER != 'f')){
       cin >> signUP1.userGENDER;
       if ((signUP1.userGENDER != 'm') && (signUP1.userGENDER != 'f')){
          cout << "ERROR: Failed requirements.\nTry again.\n";
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using std::string;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

enum Gender
{
    UNDEFINED,
    MALE,
    FEMALE
    // missing:
    // - Agender
    // - Androgyne
    // - Androgynous
    // - Bigender
    // - Cis
    // - Cisgender
    // - Cis Female
    // - Cis Male
    // - Cis Man
    // - Cis Woman
    // - Cisgender Female
    // - Cisgender Male
    // - Cisgender Man
    // - Cisgender Woman
    // - Female to Male
    // - FTM
    // - Gender Fluid
    // - Gender Nonconforming
    // - Gender Questioning
    // - Gender Variant
    // - Genderqueer
    // - Intersex
    // - Male to Female
    // - MTF
    // - Neither
    // - Neutrois
    // - Non - binary
    // - Other
    // - Pangender
    // - Trans
    // - Trans*
    // - Trans Female
    // - Trans* Female
    // - Trans Male
    // - Trans* Male
    // - Trans Man
    // - Trans* Man
    // - Trans Person
    // - Trans* Person
    // - Trans Woman
    // - Trans* Woman
    // - Transfeminine
    // - Transgender
    // - Transgender Female
    // - Transgender Male
    // - Transgender Man
    // - Transgender Person
    // - Transgender Woman
    // - Transmasculine
    // - Transsexual
    // - Transsexual Female
    // - Transsexual Male
    // - Transsexual Man
    // - Transsexual Person
    // - Transsexual Woman
    // - Two - Spirit
};

struct signUP
{
    Gender userGENDER = UNDEFINED;
};

int main() {
    signUP signUP1;
    char input;

    cout << "Gender [m]= MALE / [f]= FEMALE: ";
    do
    {
        cin >> input;
        switch (input)
        {
        case 'm':
            signUP1.userGENDER = MALE;
            cout << "male" << endl;
            break;
        case 'f':
            signUP1.userGENDER = FEMALE;
            cout << "female" << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "ERROR: Failed requirements.\nTry again.\n";
            break;
        }
    } while (input != 'm' && input != 'f');
    return 0;
}
```